# What is the use of civil drawing for an electrical engineer?

Tags: drawing

I'm reading for a BSc in electrical engineering. In this subject, I've found a subject named **civil drawing**.

Why do electrical engineers need to understand civil drawings?

Comment: Drawing in an uncivil manner is likely to offend.  But seriously, representing complex ideas in technical drawings is a key skill of a good EE.  Does your book specifically mean "civil drawing" like architecture/landscaping?  Or is it referring to a more general technical drawing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be very needed if you want to take the path of a professional engineer.

For example, if you want to design electrical or telecommunications installations in buildings, you'll likely be required to be able to actually draw the plans for the installations.

If you want to design radio installations (say cellular telephone network base station location), you'll often need to be able to do civil drawings and to read them. In some simpler building projects (for example using pre-fabricated container-based structures), from what I see at least here in Serbia, it's not uncommon for electrical engineers to do what could be considered civil engineering part as well.